# Built-in rectangle intersection function?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Someone once told me VB.net had some built-in function to check if two rectangles intersected. But I cannot find it... can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

you can use Rectangle's [IntersectsWith()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.intersectswith.aspx)

```
r1.IntersectWith(r2)
```

Comment: Works good, thanks. Well, actually I had to use r1.IntersectsWith(r2) to get the boolean value :)

Comment: ah! I didn't realize you wanted a boolean.